# submitting form in ftl to spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

i have simple form that i want to submit to a spring MVC controller.
the form goes like this:

```
<form id="assayDetailsForm" method="get" action="[@spring.url '/reports/assay/runAssayDetailsReport.htm'/]">
```

below is the spring controller java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/assay/runAssayDetailsReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView runAssayDetailsReport(@RequestParam("magentaAssayIds")String magentaAssayIds,
                                              @RequestParam("reportFormat")String reportFormat){
```

the problem is that the request never reaches the desired method i.e. "runAssayDetailsReport" and a runtime exception is always thrown.

i tried submitting the above form using AJAX call but i always get a 404 status code returned.

appreciate the help.

Comment: Make sure DispatchServlet supports mapping for urls ending in htm.

Comment: i did check and i have other requests containing htm that are working just fine.

Comment: You "listening" to GET instead of POST

Comment: @ManuZi but the "method" attribute is set to "GET" then it should run correctly.

Comment: Can you browse to that url by entering it in the address bar with an appropriate querystring? Can you browse to other addresses in that controller? I have just noticed your form action ends in .htm but your request mapping does not.